# Bind function in broadcast message

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, broadcast

I am trying to send "broadcast" message from server to many clients.

Who must call bind function server or client?

Comment: Read [FAQ] first and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: the **clients** have to issue `bind(2)`.

Sample code in Python:

Console 1

```
>>> from socket import *
>>> s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
>>> s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 33440))
>>> s.recv(10000)
```

Console 2

```
>>> from socket import *
>>> s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
>>> s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 33440))
>>> s.recv(10000)
```

Console 3

```
>>> from socket import *
>>> s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
>>> s.sendto("Hello world", ("127.255.255.255", 33440))
11
```

Then you will see `'Hello world'` on Console 1 and 2.

### Update

After you issue `s.recv(10000)` on both of Console1 and 2, you will get something like this:

```
$ LANG=C netstat -nu4ap | grep python
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33440           0.0.0.0:*                           31939/python
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33440           0.0.0.0:*                           31447/python
$ uname -a
Linux kaidev01 3.2.0-57-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 21:35:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Thank you for examples, nodakai.I`ve using similar sequence of functions in C++. But In "manuals"(http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/recvman.html) i`ve read for using recvfrom(instead recv) function from UDP, and now i use recvfrom  for recieving and also it works successfully.

Comment: This does not work for me, I get `error: [Errno 48] Address already in use`. Can two 'servers' really listen to the same address and port?

Comment: @Martol1ni Please see my update.  Did you really issue `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` on both of the two client (receiver) sockets?

Comment: I did indeed. I'm getting the error on the `bind()` command, that the address is in use.

Comment: Perhaps you'd better post a distinct question to SO with more details.